# Web page - using PDF file template instead of FPDF

Tags: php, mysql, web, pdf-generation

I have a small PHP webpage on which people can register for some events. After registration they receive email with confirmation in PDF (template with fill in fields like last name, mail address etc.).
There are so many changes in this PDF template that updating it using FPDF code take too much time.

Is there any option to create PDF templates (e.g. with Adobe Acrobat) with given "fill in fields" and then link it to web page function which fill them in using data from given MySQL table columns? Something like that:
 1. Open PDF template (instead of using FPDF code)
 2. Fill in first field in template with name from MySQL table column A
 3. Fill in second field in template with last name from MySQL table column B
 4. ...
 5. Save template as xxx.pdf and send it via mail.
Shortly speaking - how replace FPDF code creation by attaching PDF file on which I can fill in given fields using MySQL records?

Answer (score 0):

try with FPDM. You can create a PDF template with Adobe Acrobat, containing various fields. After that you can process the file with PHP and fill the fields with data from your SQL tables.
Take a look here: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php

Comment: Please put any relevant code/documentation here as links can change and make this answer irrelevant.